# Iterating over 3 dictionaries (focus on speed)

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary, nested-loops, networkx

I am new to Python and am using [NetworkX](http://networkx.github.io/) to build graphs.

In my script I have three dictionaries which perhaps need to be nested within each other:

1. dict1={'Node ID':1} -> `dict1={'0':1,'1':1,'2':1, ...}`
2. dict2={'Node ID':G.neighbors(Node ID)} -> `dict2={'0':[1,2,4], ...}`
3. dict3={'Node ID':Status} -> `dict3={'1':1, '2':0, '4':1}`

To be crystal clear, `dict1` tells me if the node is active (1) or has failed (0) [in this case, all nodes of `dict1` are active]; `dict2` contains all the nodes connected to each node of `dict1`; `dict3` tells me if all nodes connected to each node of `dict1` are either active (1) or have failed (0).

**My problem.** I want to be able to model interactions between nodes. This means that if node `0` is active (`status=1`), and has 3 nodes connected to it, if all of them have failed (`status=0`), then node `0` fails too. If only one of the connected nodes is still active, then node `0` is still active too.

**My attempt.** This is the theoretical flowchart I have envisioned, but I don't know how to translate it into Python, nor do I know if this is the best approach:

1. Loop through dict1;
2. For each key of dict1, get the values of dict2 associated with the current key of dict1;
3. For each value found in dict2, check in dict3 if their status is 0 or 1 (the values found in dict2 become keys for dict3);
4. If (and only if) all the dict3 keys found this way take on 0, change the value associated with the current dict1 key to 0.

**PS:** this flowchart is to be applied to a network of 10000 nodes, so the focus is really on speed. Nesting 3 for loops might sound like a (very) bad idea, so I would appreciate a different solution.

I apologize for not being able to put this into proper code but I am really struggling. Massive thanks!

Comment: You do not have to loop on the 3 dicts, since they provide you a direct access to their values. You only need to iterate in dict1 set of keys. But your main issue is that you can do what you want with a single set of objects.

Comment: Thanks! Would you be able to put up an "experiment" for me? I find dictionaries a territory full of possible land mines...

Comment: Did you try to setup a Node class having fields node_id, neighbours (as a list of nodes) and status? Put them in a set, and iterate on it to apply your rules. Remark: I don't know NetworkX so I'm not sure of the output you want.

Comment: Please forget `NetworkX`, I only mentioned it to give an idea of where this problem is coming from. I don't really know how to create a class as I am very very new to Python. Could you please articulate this with more details?

Comment: If you use networkx, much of this is taken care of automatically...  It'll give you the graph and all the nodes.  You can assign arbitrary node attributes.

Comment: Well thanks @Joel. How exactly does `NetworkX` take care of this? I'd be glad if you could point me toward the right direction. But as of now, these dicts are the closest thing to a solution - at least theoretically - I was able to come up with. But I don't see how `NetworkX` can do such things for me as this truly is a general problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by JoshRomRock in the comments, you could create a class like this:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, node_id, neighbours, status):
        # neighbours could be a list of other Node objects
        self.node_id = node_id
        self.neighbours = neighbours
        self.status = status

    def neighbours_status(self):
        # this method would return a list of tuples, 
        # where first tuple elem is node_id and the second is its status
        return [(n.node_id, n.status) for n in self.neighbours]
```

And later use it in your code like this:

```
 my_nodes = set()  # create set
 my_nodes.add(Node(0, [], 1))  # add a node with no neighbours
 # add some more nodes here ...

 for node in my_nodes:
     # do something with node.status, or node.node_id, or node.neighbours_status()
```

Comment: Thanks. Btw I don't understand how to use it in my situation. I don't need to add nodes - I already have 10000 of them. Also, what you define `my_nodes=set()` is something I have never seen...

Comment: In order to use the class solution, you would have to first convert your representation of the nodes to this one and later you would benefit from the ability to easily iterate through. It would also be quicker than using nested `for` loops. That's why I suggested adding them. As to the `set`, you might want to look here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html

Comment: A few questions: How would you use the `Node` class? How would you properly call it? What is the `object` the class needs? And what does it do in its three lines? I am sorry, it seems very complicated to understand...

Comment: @pzelasko That's pretty close to what I meant yesterday, thanks. I did not find time to write it properly.

Comment: @Francesco Castellani I'll try to answer your questions. You should use the `Node` class by first converting your current representation in those 3 dictionaries to a set (or a list) of `Node` objects. You can create the `Node` object in a similiar manner to what I did in the second line of the second code block. In order to use its members, just write `Node.member`; see my last comment in the answer. The `object` is the parent of the Node class, which is required to specify in Python 2 if you want a 'new-style' object (it's a detail not relevant to this question though). Hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be an ["X/Y"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) question.  I'm not convinced the way you're trying to implement your solution is the best, but I'm going to try to answer the question you've asked.  You might ask another question with slightly broader parameters.

Here's the pseudocode for what I think you're describing:

```
initialize nodes
create some initial set_of_nodes such that all have status active.
for node in set_of_nodes:
    if node has no neighbors:
        move on
    else:
        has_active_neighbor = False
        for neighbor in neighbors(node):
            add neighbor to set_of_nodes
            if neighbor's status is active:
                has_active_neighbor = True
        if has_active_neighbor = False:
            node's status becomes inactive.
```

There are some potential issues with this code.  You may iterate through and change the status of some nodes while iterating, which would mean that some of the nodes already processed would fail if you checked them again.  So you're looking at some sort of cascade.  You probably want to loop through the nodes until no changes occur.  Also, it's kind of weird that you're adding to the set while looping through it.  This is somewhat of a no-no in Python (and in general).  So I'm creating a new set of those nodes you're adding.  So depending on the rules of the system you're trying to study, this may not be the best.  Also, I don't understand why you start with just a subset as opposed to the entire network for your dict1.

Here is the implementation with networkx.  I'm going to loop through it until no changes happen.

```
import networkx as nx

# code here to define graph, assign initial statuses, and create node_set
# node attributes can be defined in several ways (one appears below)

changes = True
while changes:
    changes = False
    added_nodes = set()
    for x in node_set:
        if G.degree(x)==0 or G.node[x]['status'] == 'failed':
            continue  #nothing to see here, move on.
        else:
            has_active_neighbor=False
            for neighbor in G.neighbors(x):
                added_nodes.add(neighbor) #put it here even if it is already in node_set
                if G.node[neighbor]['status'] == 'active':
                    has_active_neighbor = True
                    break
            if not has_active_neighbor:
                changes = True
                G.node[x]['status'] = 'failed'
    if node_set.difference(added_nodes):  #True if any new nodes:
        node_set = node_set.union(added_nodes)
        changes = True

#everything is done now - here's the dictionary of statuses:
statuses = nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'status')
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't think the problem regarding nodes already processed is a real issue. I don't think I have enough space here for explanation, so I'd be glad if we could turn this into a chat to give it proper space. I might also be able to give you some details, the lack of which you have pointed out.

Comment: What I expect from this procedure is a dictionary, where the key is the node ID and the value is either 0 or 1 based on the node having failed or not.

Comment: I believe the line I've added at the end provides this.  If you want 0 or 1, edit the appropriate part of the code.  I think actually, a better name would be to have `G.node[x]['active'] = True` (or `False`), and then have a dictionary named `active` so that `active[node]` is either `True` or `False`.

Comment: There are situations where the problem you highlighted occurs - I am thinking of a random network for instance. When you have the status of a node set (say, 1) and move "geographically" away from it to process its connected nodes (say the connections of node `0` are far away from it), the status of node `0` might change according to its connections. But this is acceptable - it is modeling their interactions. What is important is the final picture - what happens from iter `0` to iter `NxN` is that the network takes on a transient status, only to become steady at the end. What do you think?

Comment: So you know, what you are describing is called a 1-core decomposition.  In general a k-core decomposition is formed by removing all nodes with fewer than k neighbors.  Then do this repeatedly until nothing is left to remove.  It will definitely reach a final state.  There's an issue though - if two initially active nodes are connected, they'll always be active.  So actually now that I think about it, the issue that you need to loop through again isn't a problem  **for this process** because you'll never change the status of an active node's neighbor to failed.

Comment: A quicker way to do this for your process is to create the graph.  Delete all nodes that are initially inactive.  then use the connected components command of networkx.  Each connected component with more than one node is made up of active nodes.  All others are inactive.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93464/discussion-between-joel-and-francesco-castellani).